# How to setenforce 0 when android startup

Tags: android, android-source, init, boot

With android phone, I want setenforce 0 permanently, I add A.rc to /system/etc/init/ folder.

A.rc like these:
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    setenforce 0

But setenforce 0 take no effect, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: What you want to achieve, Can you explain briefly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting in rc file, you can make it permissive by adding some parameters to kernel command line `(BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE)`

Ex: Add `enforcing=0 androidboot.selinux=permissive in device/<manufacturer>/<target>/BoardConfig.mk`

Comment: But I don't have the source code , I buy it from the market. so I want another way to setenforce 0 when the phone startup